# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $S^2-N$, the sphere without its north pole

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces, spheres

How would one approach the following problem?

> Write down a homeomorphism and its inverse from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to the sphere $S^2-N$ without its north pole

So I need a function $f(x,y) : \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow S^2-N$

$\mathbb{R^2}=\{(x, y) | x, y \in \mathbb{R}\}$

$S^2=\{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|d(x, y)=r\}$ where $r$ is the radius of the sphere

$S^2-N=\{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|d(x, y)=r, (x, y)\neq N\}$

I think $f$ could be some retraction but I am unsure how to formulate it

Comment: See the Riemann sphere and stereographic projection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere

Comment: The sphere is in $\mathbb{R^3}$ right? But by removing a point it can be deformed into $\mathbb{R^2}$ - is this correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: You are dealing with the surface of the sphere. It might be simpler to visualise if you consider $\mathbb{R}$ and $S- \{(0,1)\}$ first, then extend.

Comment: @Marc I am unsure how this is derived, what is the intuition behind stereographic projection in this case (in a topological sense)?

Comment: @copper.hat Would it not be $S-(0, 0, 1)$ since we are in $\mathbb{R^3}$ ? so: $f: (x, y, z)-(0, 0, 1) \rightarrow (x, y)$... so topologically eliminating one element of $z$, eliminates $z$ completely..?

Comment: My point was to try a smaller dimensional (but easily translatable) problem first...

Comment: @copper.hat ok thanks, yes that is helpful. So removing a point from $S$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ gives a line $[a, b]$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ so I can see how this would work (although maybe only $(a, b)$ would work since doesn't it have to be open like the space $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: $(a,b)$  is homeomorphic to the real line. I don't see how you get a segment $[a,b]$ from $S$ with a point removed. You should get $(a,b)$.

Comment: yes I see it now. So puncturing a hole in the sphere would give a curved polygon which is homeomorphic to the square which is homeomorphic to the plane.. I find it hard to construct an explicit homeomorphism though

Comment: Here is one way: Draw $S$ and draw the line $L= \{(x,-1)\}_x$. Pick some $x$ and extend the line from $N=(0,1)$ that passes through $(x,0)$ to the line $L$. Define $\phi(x)$ to be the (unique) point where the line intersects $S$.